# How to add matplotlib from python3.6 to Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

In Window, I installed python3.6 and, installed matplotlib by commandline:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

After installation, I was running matplotlib in python console,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt --> not error
import matplotlib.pylab as plb --> not error
```

In python36\lib\site-packages

[image: site-packages]

I want in blender to use the matplotlib library in python, Can I copy the matplotlib in `python36\lib\site-packages` of Python into the `Blender\2.78 \python\lib\site-packages`?

I tried copying but only importing matplotlib, but when `import matplotlib.pylot as plt the error is as follows

[image: errors]

I do not know how to fix it, please help me

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try to remove blender's embedded python and fall back to the default python on your windows system? I've been using this method for a while and it hasn't disappointed yet (using Matplotlib among many other packages in Blender).

Comment: I removed /blender/2.78/python folder, but can not open blender

Comment: You must have a default python on your windows machine which is exactly the same version as the one Blender is using